# Looking for my grandfather in Germany

Tags: 20th-century, germany, bavaria

I'm trying to locate my mums real father. She was born in Bad Tölz, Germany in 1947 and brought up by her maternal aunt & uncle. She came to Aust when she was 3 years old & was never told who her real father was. Her mum died at 40 and she was bought up by her aunt & uncle and was told they were her parents but later in her life she found out they weren't & she never ever got to meet her real father. Can you please help me try & locate him? I'm in Berlin at the moment on holiday & I have my mothers documents etc so if there is somewhere I can visit that would be helpful?

Comment: Nicole, it's not allowed to post identifying information about possibly-living individuals on this site so I have edited your question to remove it.

Comment: I am glad a very useful looking answer has been posted but have voted to close this question as being outside the scope of GFH-SE because the help says "it is not about:
Locating identifiable [potentially] living individuals".  Good luck with your search all the same.

Comment: @PolyGeo and others voting to close can we discuss at http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/1747/104.

Answer (score 9):

You'll need to visit the *Einwohnermeldeamt* (registration office), which is usually a part of the *Stadtverwaltung* (city administration), in Bad Tölz, ideally in person. As long as you can prove that your mother was indeed your mother (copies of your own and your mother's birth certificates and ideally your grandmother's death certificate along with your ID should be sufficient), they're required to give you all the data they have on your mother, including her parents and other ancestors if known and available. This is generally not free (costs run between 5€ ad 25€ per person, usually on the lower end). The key word here is "*Melderegisterauskunft*".

The address of the *Einwohnermeldeamt* can be easily found via Google searching for "einwohnermeldeamt (city name)". In case of Bad Tölz, it's:

> Stadtverwaltung Bad Tölz
>
> Am Schloßplatz 1
>
> 83646 Bad Tölz

If you can't go there by yourself, call them. There's a good chance you'll be able to talk to someone who speaks passable English if your German isn't good enough.